# (PHP/Wordpress) Remove characters easily, but not '$' when string is output of shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace, shortcode

**NOTE: I've answered my own question below, but posting this anyway for someone else in my situation to learn...**

---

This is driving me insane.

Here's the scenario. There are a million questions here about removing characters like '$' from simple strings (eg. `$string = '$10.00'`) and I can do that just fine.

However... when the string originates from shortcode output (eg. $string = do_shortcode($mycode), I just can't do it. I can remove the 1's and 0's and .'s but the $ won't budge.

Note: The shortcode I'm using is 'Wordpress Currency Switcher' (wpcs_price). My newbie mind tells me that the problem is my string isn't a string at all, but live code or some weird type of array I don't understand.

Example.

```
function justwork() {
$rawprice = 10.00;
$rawpriceSC = '[wpcs_price value=\''.$rawprice.'\']'; 
$rawpriceOUT = do_shortcode($rawpriceSC); /* This will output $10.00 */
$finalprice = str_replace('$','',$rawpriceOUT);
echo $finalprice;
}

add_shortcode('justwork', 'justwork');
```

This will result in:

`'$10.00'`    ($ not removed)

Using the same code on a different character (Eg. the '.') works just fine. 
Eg.

```
$finalprice = str_replace('.','',$rawpriceOUT);
```

And the output will be:
'$1000'

The $ just won't budge. I've tried substr,trim,preg, lots of other stuff, and I soon realised all is not what it seems, it's carrying some baggage. So I tried capturing the output buffer, and still the resultant string behaved odd.

Any help... oh gosh please, going insane on this one.

**ANSWER**

While reviewing all the methods I'd looked at, one came up I hadn't.

```
echo htmlentities($finalprice);
```

And guess what this output?

```
<span class="wpcs_price" id="wpcs_58c296db36aa3" data-amount=10 ><span class="wpcs_price_symbol">&#36;</span>10.00</span>
```

OK. So either I need to use & # 3 6 ; instead of $, or I can operate on that whole mess to get my `10.00`. Geeze.

Comment: Post the answer in the `answer` section, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that simply replacing the '$' with '& # 3 6 ;' (remove spaces) works fine.

```
function justwork() {
$rawprice = 10.00;
$rawpriceSC = '[wpcs_price value=\''.$rawprice.'\']';
$rawpriceOUT = do_shortcode($rawpriceSC);

$price = str_replace('&#36;', '', $rawpriceOUT) ;

echo $price;

}   

add_shortcode('justwork', 'justwork');
```